# What happened to Doctor Octopus?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

I'm used to Doctor Octopus looking like this:

[image: comic panel with old-style Otto]

Except in the most recent comic I've seen featuring him, he appears more disfigured, with a breathing mask and tubes:

[image: newer, somehow disfigured Otto]

I realise that he was diagnosed with some illness or injury that threatened his life, and has taken steps in the form of armouring/arming himself, but how has he become the bundle of tubes and wires I see before me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia's Entry on [Doctor Octopus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Octopus) reveals:

> During the Dark Reign storyline, Doctor Octopus learns that due to
> injuries suffered from his many battles, his body is failing, giving
> him only months to live. He has now modified himself to be mentally
> connected to his own army of miniature 'octobots', and has added four
> additional appendages to his harness. He used the octobots to tak
> control of all of the technology in New York City and planned to turn
> it into a paradise under his control, though he subconsciously also
> targeted Spider-Man, and disrupted the wedding plans of his ex, Aunt
> May. Spider-Man and the Human Torch eventually tracked down his base,
> save the captive J. Jonah Jameson Sr. (May's fiancee), Carlie Cooper,
> and Norah Winters, and finally destroyed Doctor Octopus' hold over the
> city. Doctor Octopus is then able to escape (still holding power over
> his octobots) and vows a "terrible revenge".

The explanation for the changes in his appearance are due to his very mortal frame engaged in combat with superhuman opponents.

> Doctor Octopus has begun wearing a full-body armor suit due to a
> crippling illness caused by the amount of punishment he has sustained
> over the years - made even worse by the fact that his ability to take
> damage is still at a human norm, even if he can deliver a superhuman
> level of punishment. To compensate, he has covered his entire body
> with his new suit, his normal arms are bound to his chest, and four
> additional tentacles have been added to his harness. He also has
> telepathic control over an army of "Octobots", small, octopus-like
> drones.

The goal of his new look is to provide him with increased physical resistance to damage as his foes have learned over the years that HE is the weakest link in his assemblage of technology. He has also increased the number of arms, and thus damage dealing capacity as well as adding to an arsenal of smaller drones to either draw fire or deal damage during combat.

Comment: But the tubes? That seems like the most glaring change. I could have recognised him in the comic had it just been more arms and armour, but my main point is the tubes. I'm guessing it's just down his own alterations to his body...

Comment: I suspect the damage on his body requires life sustaining technology, which would and should include his head. Now as to why he has the tube EXPOSED like that seems a weakness that begs to be exploited. However with eight arms he should be more than formidable enough if the eight work as well as the four did.